# lambda expression for one to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, one-to-many

I am sure this is stupid question, but I looked for an answer and couldn't find one.

I have tables

1. Customers contain three columns: userId, name and orderId.
2. Orders contain three columns: orderId, userId, price.

The relationship between the tables are ONE customers TO MANY orders.

I want to sum the orders price for certain user.
It should look something like this:

```
double totalPrice = currentUser.Orders.Sum(x=>x.price);
```

This doesn't work. What is the right way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: 'That doesn't work' - an error or the value of totalPrice is not what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal totalPrice = users.SelectMany(user => user.Orders)
                         .Sum(order => (decimal?)order.Price) ?? 0;
```

or

```
decimal totalPrice = (from user in users
                     from order in user.Orders
                     select (decimal?)order.Price).Sum() ?? 0;
```

**UPDATE**:

It's inappropriate using `double` to represent financial values as it's a binary *floating* point type. Casting the `product.Price` to `decimal?` indicates that it's a nullable decimal hence the need to use the `Value` property to get the actual value (if it exists, determined via `HasValue`)

Comment: Might be worth explaining why you need this.  It's because if there are no records in orders (that apply to the user) the result of the sum is null which produces a casting exception if expecting a double.

Comment: I've just done a revision that has some explanation to why use `decimal?`, this indicates that it's a `nullable` decimal so there wont be any casting exception if there is a null order price for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should select the user from your entity object (in this case, userId=1)

```
           int i= users.Single(x => x.UserID== 1).Orders.Sum(x => x.Price);
```